# Command Prompt Batchfile output to VB textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a number of batch files and I'm trying to wrap a GUI around them so they are easily available for some of my users all in one place.

At the moment, I've got 2 buttons and a Textbox.  Each button calls the same batch file with a different working directory (though in production, the batch files will be different).  At the moment, all it does is call 'DIR /A /B" to list a directory contents.

```
DIR /A /B
exit
```

I've got the following code: (Button 2 is identical, but with a different working directory)

```
Public Class Form1
Dim P As New Process
Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow() = True
    P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    P.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\temp"
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    P.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\temp\dircmd.cmd"
    P.Start()
    P.SynchronizingObject = TextBox1
    Try
        P.BeginOutputReadLine()
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & "Begin output" & vbCrLf
        SW = P.StandardInput
        SW.WriteLine()
        MsgBox("WriteLine()")
        SW.Dispose()
        SW.Close()
        MsgBox("StreamWriter Close")
        P.WaitForExit()
        P.CancelOutputRead()
        P.Close()
        MsgBox("Process Close")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayOutput(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal output As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Textbox1.AppendText(output.Data() & vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

My problem is that I'm getting the output from each command, however its getting duplicated.  First button, first time works fine.  Second button works, but everything is listed twice.  Going back to first button, everything is listed 3 times. I initially thought I needed to clear the StreamWriter buffer, but its not repeating old info, its just repeating new info and I'm not sure why.

```
Begin output

C:\temp>DIR /A /B 
bob.txt
dircmd.cmd
LocationRouting.xml
TempFrogsareNOTCool.txt
Test.txt
test2.txt
Test3.txt

C:\temp>exit

Begin output 2

C:\>DIR /A /B 
C:\>DIR /A /B 
$Recycle.Bin
$Recycle.Bin
Config.Msi
Config.Msi
Documents and Settings  
Documents and Settings
<snip>

C:\>exit
C:\>exit
```

Comment: Dim P As New Process <- put that in the button click ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using a `Using` construct to instantiate and dispose of the Process:

Option A:

```
        Using P As Process = New Process
            P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            P.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\temp"
            P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
            P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            P.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\temp\dircmd.cmd"
            P.Start()
            Dim sOutput As String
            Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = P.StandardOutput
                sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
            OutputTextBox.Text = sOutput
            P.Close()

        End Using
```

Option B:

```
  Private Sub TestDirOutputButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TestDirOutputButton.Click
        Using P As Process = New Process
            AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
            P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow() = True
            P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            P.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\temp"
            P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
            P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            P.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\temp\dircmd.cmd"
            P.Start()
            P.SynchronizingObject = OutputTextBox
            Try
                P.BeginOutputReadLine()
                OutputTextBox.Text = OutputTextBox.Text & vbCrLf & "Begin output" & vbCrLf
                SW = P.StandardInput
                SW.WriteLine()
                MsgBox("WriteLine()")
                SW.Dispose()
                SW.Close()
                MsgBox("StreamWriter Close")
                P.WaitForExit()
                P.CancelOutputRead()
                P.Close()
                MsgBox("Process Close")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try
            RemoveHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to resolve my duplication issues, however if I go through and comment out those Msgboxs, I get the "Begin output" line, but nothing else.  If I put the Msgbox back in, I get the expected response.  Any idea what that Msgbox could be doing?

Comment: The Msgbox probably causes it to wait long enough for the command to finish.

Comment: Just getting back to this after a few days off....Option A works, however it seems to be taking all the output and then dropping it into the text box all at once.  For a short script, thats fine, but some of the scripts i will be using will be longer and I'll need to see output as its happening, not once its all complete.  I wasn't able to get Option B to work for me, but I'm going to review the code again to see if I messed something up.

Comment: Would you consider performing all the actions you need directly via VB code?

Comment: That was actually my first thought, but was hoping to avoid reinventing the wheel.  Seems I need a better wheel!